# Ubuntu Touch - Dekko email auto select after deleting

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email-client

I use Dekko email client and when I read and then delete an email, the next email is not automatically displayed. Only a blank screen is displayed and I have to physically select the next email in the folder. This is not too much of a big issue, but it gets annoying that the next email is not automatically displayed. I would expect that when i delete an email, the next one in the folder is shown and I can keep on reading and or deleting emails.

Comment: I have been watching the Dekko space for a bit now waiting for some bug fixes to be pushed out. However, there does not seem to be much happening with the Dekko development. This is a shame as it has the potential to be a good email client.

Comment: I have raised a bug for this in Launchpas https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko/+bug/1647110

Comment: Comment added to the launchpad rrcord.